# How can i make the div clickable with entire background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I added background image in `parent div` The div width is `100%` I make the redirection when you click the div (It all works fine) But i want to redirect the div only if you click from left to right of `100px;` For Example Here is the fiddle i called the div with background image whenever i click any portion of div it get redirected. But My question is i want to redirect only if you click the image from left to right within `100px;` Is it possible to achieve that any suggestion would be great.
http://jsfiddle.net/a39Va/25/

```
$('#loginContainer').click(function(e) { 

    window.open('http://google.com');
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: So get the click location, look at the event object.

Comment: why not just place the banner in a sepearte div within the container and make that clickable - http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/a39Va/30/

Comment: Kindly mark as answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below (http://jsfiddle.net/a39Va/31/)

```
 <div id="loginContainer">
      <div class="clickable"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.clickable{
    width:100px;
    height:100%;

}
```

JS

```
$('.clickable').click(function(e) { 

    window.open('http://google.com');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The most suitable thing to do would be using an `image map`

It helps you to define specific regions for which you need specific clickable areas. You may define area of any shape by just defining the coordinates fro the region.

Please look [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#loginContainer').click(function(e) { 
  if(e.pageX < 100)
    window.open('http://google.com');
});
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a39Va/28/)

Answer (score 0):

try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/83H3c/)

HTML

```
 <div id="loginContainer">
     <div class="clickable">
     </div>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.clickable{
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

JS

```
$('.clickable').click(function(e) { 

    window.open('http://google.com');
});
```